# undefined method `validate_integrity'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, carrierwave

I wrote a little rails app with file uploading. I use mongoDB - mongoid, and CarrieWave.

../models/data_file.rb:

```
class DataFile
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :title, type: String
   mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

../uploaders/file_uploader.rb:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :grid_fs
  def store_dir
    uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

When I start my root page I get this error:

```
undefined method `validate_integrity' for FileUploader:Module
```

Maybe the reason is in mongoDB?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use this gem? https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid

Comment: yes, i do. also use 'mongoid-grid_fs' gem.
Rails version is 4.